# Using the bibtex format (with JabRef) as a non-bib key-value database in LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, jabref, key-value, xkeyval

This might sound a bit odd: I am using JabRef for maintaining a database which does *not* content bibliographical data in the first place:

```
@Person{caesar,
  date          = {100-44BC},
  comment       = {tyran},
  description   = {rebel},
  locationbirth = {Rome},
  locationdeath = {Rome},
  name          = {Iulius Caesar, Caius},
  shortname     = {Caesar},
  works         = {Bello Gallico},
}

@Work{bello:gallico,
  author = {Caesar},
  title  = {Bello Gallico},
  date   = {58-51BC},
}
```

This works pretty nicely since all the fields in JabRef can be customized and I can group various entries and search the database quickly.

Now the difficult part:

### How can I use and integrate the data in a TeX-document?

> Note: I am aware of `datatool` which would be quite the tool to use
>   and its gui (`datatooltk`) but I cannot run it on my system (...
>   always Java-issues) but I would like to use JabRef and the dataset
>   with its `bibtex`-format.

Is it possible to have relationships among entries? Like `works={\getdata{bello:gallico}{title}},` (see below in MWE)?

First attempt using `biblatex`

---

At a first glance it looks like a common and modified `\cite`-command should do the job. I failed. 
And it might conflict with the citation style one uses.
But maybe someone has a nice solution with `biblatex`?

Second attempt using `keyval`/`xkeyval`

---

On the other hand it is also "just" a key-value list divided into several entries. So `xkeyval` might be the right tool doing it.
But I fail integrating the dataset document and passing the values to a `\setkeys...`/`\define@key` command.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\newcommand\getdata[2]{%
  % load file `datasets.tex` and search for needed values.
  % \setkeys{#1}{#2}
    % \define@key{#1}{#2}{##1}
}


\begin{filecontents}{datasets.tex}
    @Person{caesar,
  date          = {100-44BC},
  comment       = {tyran},
  description   = {rebel},
  locationbirth = {Rome},
  locationdeath = {Rome},
  name          = {Iulius Caesar, Caius},
  shortname     = {Caesar},
  works         = {\getdata{bello:gallico}{title}},
} 

@Person{cicero,
  date          = {106-43BC},
  comment       = {great author},
  description   = {Statesman, rhetor, author},
  locationbirth = {Arpinum},
  locationdeath = {Formiae},
  name          = {Tullius Cicero, Marcus},
  shortname     = {Cicero},
  works         = {\getdata{de:re:publica}{title}, \getdata{de:amicitia}{title}},
}

@Work{de:re:publica,
  author = {\getdata{cicero}{name}},
  title  = {De re publica},
  date   = {54-51BC},
}

@Work{de:amicitia,
  author = {\getdata{cicero}{name}},
  title  = {Laelius de amicitia},
  date   = {44BC},
}

@Work{bello:gallico,
  author = {\getdata{caesar}{name}},
  title  = {Bello Gallico},
  date   = {58-51BC},
}
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document} 
\getdata{caesar}{name} was bon in 
\getdata{caesar}{locationbirth}.
He lived \getdata{caesar}{date} and died in
\getdata{casear}{locationdeath}.

Our friend \getdata{cicero}{name} lived longer (\getdata{cicero}{date}) and he can be described as: 
\getdata{cicero}{description}.


% if this works it would be awesome!
\getdata{cicero}{name} published many important works: \getdata{cicero}{works}.
\getdata{caesar}{name} however only one big shot: 
\getdata{bello:gallico}{title} written in 
\getdata{bello:gallico}{date}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should work fine with biblatex. I have an address database in this format which I use with biblatex. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111fischer.pdf.

Comment: And you already have published it in the DTK - which would have been my next step. I am too late obviously. Thank you for the link and hint.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In the paper you provide via the link there are only hard-coded `\cite`-examples. I am rather interested in a `\cite` command to which I can pass the relevant field I want to cite. Otherwise I would need to define as many `\cite`-commands as many fields I have in a dataset.

Comment: There is a generic \citefield command. Check the docu.

Comment: For relationships in general you could use the `crossref` field (JabRef also supports it), it allows to link to another entry by key. Typically used for child-parent relationships like a chapter linking to a book entry.

Comment: I'd look for something like the `related` field. You'd probably need several such fields to be able to have several relations.

Comment: yes, one `related` field is not enough... I set up a dataset with a `.dbx` on GitHub: https://github.com/LukasCBossert/bibtex-database help is welcome!